# File name (title) of the document is coming as blank in Excel client for Office JS addin

Tags: office-js

Simple repro steps -
Create an Excel app for task pane app for Excel client application 
Use the below function to print the document name in the task pane
Build and add the addin manifest in the trusted Add-in catalog so you can insert it into any Excel document. 
Launch Excel (a new blank workbook will come up)
Click the button to execute the below code
You will see blank string in the workbook name
Next- save the workbook and then click the button again you will see the correct name displayed in your add-in

```
function getDataFromSelection() {
        Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

                    Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {

                        app.showNotification('The document URL is:', '"' + Office.context.document.url + '"');


                    })

                    }

            }
        );
```

I have an app for Excel

I am trying to read the name of the URL (document name)
It works fine in online 
When the same addin is used in Excel client app it gives correct result for a saved document.

But

When the a new workbook is launched with name eg - Book1.xlsx and we try to print the Office.context.document.url to get the name, we get an empty string.

Is this by design or a bug? is there a way to get the name of the default unsaved document?

Comment: I have started an internal conversation about this with the team... let us discuss, and we'll get back to you...

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Michael ! Will await to hear more on this.

Answer (score 1):

Upon investigation, it seems like the URL property was indeed designed for Online scenarios, so just a regular file on the computer or an unsaved file will not be returned by this.  We have jotted down a backlog item to expose the filename (just the name, not the path) across all platforms, though, so this should be forthcoming in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the update Michael ! I really appreciate your responsiveness on this. I would like to add that a regular file on the computer is giving correct result, only the unsaved file is NOT.

Comment: Oh, really?  I didn't realize that a saved file did.  Could you give an example of what that path looks like?  Thanks!

Comment: The path for a saved file looks like this -The document URL is:

"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Book1.xlsx"                                                                                           Whereas for a Blank unsaved document the same addin results a blank string - The document URL is:
""

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't realize we were exposing the full path even on the computer.  Let me pass this on to some folks on my team.

Comment: To clarify, though:  for your scenario, do you care only about the **file name**, or the full path?

Comment: Sorry i was on vacation so late response, At this point, we care about the filename, but fullpath would be a more desired state.

Comment: Just wanted to gently check if there was any update?

Comment: We are looking at adding this in the next wave of the APIs (currently slated for ExcelApi 1.5... which, if I had to make a wild guess, would be publically available in late spring -- though both the release timeline and the spot on the 1.5 set is very much in flux)

Comment: Do we have an update on this one? I am running into the same issue. It seems when I run "Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync" the res.value.url is coming back as empty. The workaround as suggested above is to save the file and then "refershing" the Add Ins or restarting Excel. When you do so, it getFilePropertiesAsync work well. Else, it is returns empty.

Comment: @Tony, I have left the team several years ago. I suggest you raise a new question or an issue on the Office.js GitHub repo, to get the current API owners to look at this. All the best!